# Sharing work in a competitive environment

Tags: employer-relations

Suppose someone helped me in a particular work in a particular field. I would obviously thank the person for the help. And let's say that after a few days, that person found out that I have completed my task and that person would like to use it in his/her task. I do not want to give away my 1 month hard work just for that person to use and edit it in his/her task. Then that person would simply say "I helped you before, so it's your turn to help."

**Some background:** We work on a research based project, where there's no kind of teamwork. Actually, there is a competition between individuals to produce the best outcomes. When this person helped me, he/she used a *past project* as an example. Now, this person wants the information from the research I'm working on my *new project*.

What must I do to solve this problem? I did say NO but that person would just keep bragging about his/her assistance. How do I deal with such a cases?

Comment: I think you're going to have to give us more information about your job. If you were to let them use your work, what is the benefit to them and what is the cost to you?

Comment: The task is same, only the contents varies depending on self research. The person would benefit by using my ideas. And I do not want my ideas to be stolen and used by somebody else.

Comment: Ok, let me put it another way. I'm in software. I work with others to benefit a company. Whether somebody helped me or not, I would happily give them my code if it saved them time, because ultimately it benefits the company. So I'm trying to figure out what you do that makes you work as individuals rather than a team. And if there is a good reason, why was he happy to help you?

Comment: This is not a team work. It's an individual work. He/She helped me because I asked. And that person didn't use his/her project to help me, instead he/she used a past project as an example. And there is competition between individuals to produce the best outcome of a research based project. I certainly would not want my ideas to be stolen by my competitor.

Comment: I thought you might say research. Ok, thanks. That clarifies.

Comment: Yes. So how do I deal with it?

Comment: @deepz, that person could mention in his/her work that in some parts he/she has used your results

Comment: @superM Not a chance. Do you know that it's a self research work? No one would mention a competitor's name in his/her bibliography.

Comment: None of this makes sense as a competent way to run a company.

Comment: IMHO, this whole situation sounds deeply dysfunctional to me -- sort of the research equivalent of [The Prisoner's Dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma).

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: @squeemish This question is not about the company.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It doesn't matter where I am from, if you have any answers to this question then feel free to post them

Comment: @deepz, My comment was not an answer to your question because it was a *comment*. You come across as someone who is fairly young, and, as such, you probably have not worked in a large number of environments -- academic, research, or commercial. I have. And it is my considered opinion that the environment you are describing -- dog-eat-dog, zero-sum game, I only win when you lose -- this environment is the antithesis of every group I have worked with in the last 40 years, including the University of Illinois at Chicago , Stanford, Xerox Palo Alto, and many commercial firms.

Comment: @deepz I find your choice of words in your comments interesting, regarding that you are the one asking others.  To put it briefly the country _IS_ important due to cultural differences between countries, which in turn mean that the way say an american and an indian should approach this _will_ be different.  If you do not understand and appreciate this you will appear as abrasive to the persons around you as you did to me in your comment.  You may not want that.  Good luck in solving your issue.

Comment: @PeterRowell I understand that you're experienced. And what I'm going through is quite different. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You're right, I'm sorry I misunderstood you.

Comment: @deepz That's why I posted it is a comment and not an answer, as it was my observation of your description of the situation.  No need for hostility towards everyone

Comment: @squeemish oh okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a competitive environment, there will always be people who try to turn any situation to their advantage. Some of those people will give up a little, appearing to be altruistic, so that they can bring that up when they want a lot.

These people generally know what they're doing. It's a calculated move, rather than an accidental one.

But just in case this individual doesn't know the difference between what they did for you and what they're asking you to do for them, please do explain it. Once. If they genuinely hadn't thought about it, they'll back off pretty quickly.

If they then continue to argue semantics and play a game of emotional blackmail, don't bother engaging. Just say "It's not going to happen. I'm sorry if you feel I've taken advantage of you; feel free not to help me in future. But I'm not doing what you ask."

Then just walk away.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not suggesting this will be easy. But I am telling you that people who manipulate other people like this cannot be negotiated with. Nothing they ever do for you will be altruistic, but they will always argue that it was. You're better off in the long-run if you cut yourself off from the conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've understood it clearly. I know its quite difficult for me to tell that person to back off because by just telling "NO" wasn't that easy in the first place, especially by a friendly person like me. Now that I got the whole point I will certainly know how to deal with such people presently and in the future. Thanks for your explanation. It's very good and straight forward :)

Answer (score 3):

Emotional blackmail is completely in your mind.  It is not something that somebody can do to you, it is an internal conflict we inflict upon ourselves based on how we perceive ourselves.

The majority of people truly believe they are good people, even when they are objectively not.  It is a human trait.  This internal conflict you have right now is not really about your desire to be a good person however, because no matter what course of action you take, you will subconciously find a way to justify your chosen actions in your own mind.

Instead when somebody makes an unreasonable request and attempts to use **guilt** to coerce you, then what you are experiencing is **not** your desire to be a good person, but instead *your desire to be perceived as a good person by others.*

What I mean of course is that no matter what you will think of yourself, you have an emotional need to be seen as a good person to other people.  This is fine of course for small things, help him out with his project sure, but you need to protect your research for your own benefit so what he asks is crossing the line.

If you have high self esteem, and respect for yourself, then you will have respect for your personal boundaries and will not tolerate when somebody is crossing the line.  In any aspect of life you should never allow people to cross the line, regardless of your internal emotional conflict or how others perceive you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This approach also sounds fair to me. However there is a big difference between helping and giving out my research information. That person wanted my work, and not help. I do not want to portray myself as a complete "miss goody two shoes." I just do what I feel it's right whether the opposite person likes it or not. I totally agree with "personal boundary." So your approach is very good actually. Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, yes and no. Emotional blackmail is something that somebody does to you, it's a deliberate act of manipulation using the victim's emotions against them, but I'd agree that the victim has to be complicit to some extent.